# identification of conditional joint density from conditional marginal densities

Tags: probability

I have the following factor model:

$W_1 = \theta + \eta + \nu_1$

$W_2 = \mu_2(\theta)+\eta+\nu_2$

where $\eta$, $\nu_1$, and $\nu_3$ are mutually independent given $\theta$. I already know the following distributions:

$f_{W_1,W_2}, f_{W_t|\theta}, f_{\eta+\nu_t|\theta},$ and $f_{\theta}$ for $t=1,2$. Note that $W_1$ and $W_2$ are not independent given $\theta$ because of $\eta$.

Can I recover $f_{W_1,W_2|\theta}$ based on the above information? It is possible under the assumption $W_1 \perp \theta|W_3$, but this is too strong in my model.

How about if I add more structure such that

$W_1 = \theta + a(\theta)(\eta + \nu_1)$

$W_2 = \mu_2(\theta)+ a(\theta)(\eta+\nu_2)$

where $\eta$ and $\nu_t$ are now independent of $\theta$ and is still independent to each other. Also, I know the function $a(\cdot)$. Does this help to recover $f_{W_1,W_2|\theta}$.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.